# How should I implement recursion method to find number of ways to form max heap in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, minmax-heap

If dp[n] stores the number of ways of forming max heap containing n elements, then we have.

```
dp[n] = nCr(n - 1, n1) * dp[n1] * dp[n2];
```

i.e.

1. Select n1 elements out of n - 1 for left subtree.
2. Elements in left subtree can form max heap in dp[n1] ways.
3. Elements in right subtree can form max heap in dp[n2] ways.

How to calculate n1 and n2?

Comment: Is this a quiz? homework? It's definitely not a question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're missing the loop that encloses the formula you posted.  You vary `n1` from `1` through `n-1`.  If "max heap" requires that you consume all `n` nodes, then you have simply `n2 = n-n1`.  If you can use fewer, then you need another loop to vary `n2` from `1` through `n-n1`.

Return the sum of all those computed quantities.